# Radzen FilterOperator functionality

Tags: filter, datagrid, blazor

I'm using a RadzenGrid in a blazor application... When I have no filter operator set on a column the column will only filter exact match situations, so that if the value is 133.38 the search results will be empty if I filter it with the value 133.

I want to be able to filter the grid with a greater than value for now (it would be ideal to be able to have a filter mode selector i.e. (Equal, Greater Than, Less Than) however I can settle for now with simply getting a Greater Than filter operator working.  Any help is appreciated.

```
            <RadzenGridColumn TItem="TimeCard" Property="TotalHours" FilterOperator="IsGreaterThan" Title="Total Hours" TextAlign="Radzen.TextAlign.Right">
                <Template Context="data">
                    @String.Format("{0:0.00}", data.TotalHours)
                </Template>
            </RadzenGridColumn>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use this:

```
FilterOperator="FilterOperator.GreaterThan"
```